# Background Streaming Effect make other view not performing well

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application that playes audio file and video from server. For that i have used Avplayer view controller. but my problem is that when the audio or video song is playing then i go to the next view in that i have song list that is comming from server  and displayed in the UItableview but tableview not scrolling well when i scroll it scroll after some times. may be because of the player.